# Getting Google Spreadsheet Cell Value in Android

Tags: android, arrays, json

This would be just a simple JSON parsing which is confusing for me as it works in Javascript but I don't know how to work it out in Java.
I have got the response at the end of the post (put it there to keep the question clean) and trying to get these values from that string (you can find in the response):

> "This is first senstence." and "Number111"
>   "This is second sentences." and "Number222"

The keys are `["gsx$name"]["$t"]` and `["gsx$comment"]["$t"]`

I am trying this Java code which is not quite there:

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
        try{
            JSONObject array = new JSONObject(response);
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            JSONArray array1 = array.getJSONArray("entry.feed");
            Log.i("httpget", array1.toString());
            //JSONArray array2 = array1.getJSONArray("entry");
            for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length() ; i++){
                list.add(array1.getJSONObject(i).getString("gsx$name"));
            }
            mTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
            mTextView.setText("Response is: "+array1.toString());
        } catch(Exception e){
        }
    }
}
```

The code that works in Javascript:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="results"></div> 
<script type="text/javascript">


 // ID of the Google Spreadsheet
 var spreadsheetID = "1Sp18_fOs8SSP_fwB54lv7IoL42uDaioZM1LTRD4rL8o";

 // Make sure it is public or set to Anyone with link can view 
 var url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/" + spreadsheetID + "/od6/public/values?alt=json";

 $.getJSON(url, function(data) {

  var entry = data.feed.entry;


  $(entry).each(function(){
     for (var prop in this["gsx$name"]){alert(this["gsx$name"][prop]);}
    // Column names are name, age, etc.
    $('.results').prepend('<h2>'+this.gsx$name.$t+'</h2><p>'+this.gsx$age.$t+'</p>');
  });

 });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The response from Google Get call:

```
{"version":"1.0","encoding":"UTF-8","feed":{"xmlns":"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom","xmlns$openSearch":"http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/","xmlns$gsx":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006/extended","id":{"$t":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1Sp18_fOs8SSP_fwB54lv7IoL42uDaioZM1LTRD4rL8o/od6/public/values"},"updated":{"$t":"2016-03-08T11:19:18.322Z"},"category":[{"scheme":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006","term":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#list"}],"title":{"type":"text","$t":"Sheet1"},"link":[{"rel":"alternate","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Sp18_fOs8SSP_fwB54lv7IoL42uDaioZM1LTRD4rL8o/pubhtml"},{"rel":"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#feed","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1Sp18_fOs8SSP_fwB54lv7IoL42uDaioZM1LTRD4rL8o/od6/public/values"},{"rel":"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#post","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1Sp18_fOs8SSP_fwB54lv7IoL42uDaioZM1LTRD4rL8o/od6/public/values"},{"rel":"self","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1Sp18_fOs8SSP_fwB54lv7IoL42uDaioZM1LTRD4rL8o/od6/public/values?alt\u003djson"}],"author":[{"name":{"$t":"amirfarazmand"},"email":{"$t":"amirfarazmand@gmail.com"}}],"openSearch$totalResults":{"$t":"2"},"openSearch$startIndex":{"$t":"1"},"entry":[{"id":{"$t":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1Sp18_fOs8SSP_fwB54lv7IoL42uDaioZM1LTRD4rL8o/od6/public/values/cokwr"},"updated":{"$t":"2016-03-08T11:19:18.322Z"},"category":[{"scheme":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006","term":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#list"}],"title":{"type":"text","$t":"This is first senstence."},"content":{"type":"text","$t":"comment: Number111"},"link":[{"rel":"self","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1Sp18_fOs8SSP_fwB54lv7IoL42uDaioZM1LTRD4rL8o/od6/public/values/cokwr"}],"gsx$name":{"$t":"This is first senstence."},"gsx$comment":{"$t":"Number111"}},{"id":{"$t":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1Sp18_fOs8SSP_fwB54lv7IoL42uDaioZM1LTRD4rL8o/od6/public/values/cpzh4"},"updated":{"$t":"2016-03-08T11:19:18.322Z"},"category":[{"scheme":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006","term":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#list"}],"title":{"type":"text","$t":"This is second sentences."},"content":{"type":"text","$t":"comment: Number222"},"link":[{"rel":"self","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1Sp18_fOs8SSP_fwB54lv7IoL42uDaioZM1LTRD4rL8o/od6/public/values/cpzh4"}],"gsx$name":{"$t":"This is second sentences."},"gsx$comment":{"$t":"Number222"}}]}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code extract the `gsx$name` and `gsx$comment` from your response:

```
try {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
    JSONObject feed = jsonObject.getJSONObject("feed");
    JSONArray entryArray = feed.getJSONArray("entry");

    for (int i = 0; i < entryArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject entry = entryArray.getJSONObject(i);

        String name = entry.getJSONObject("gsx$name").getString("$t");
        String comment = entry.getJSONObject("gsx$comment").getString("$t");

        Log.d(TAG, String.format("%s - %s", name, comment));
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```